# Erro "Using $this when not in object context" no Slim framework

Tags: php, slim

Estou com o seguinte erro:

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   C:\Users\PC\Desktop\slim_framework\app\Controllers\HomeController.php
>   on line 10

**composer.json**

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.9",
        "slim/php-view": "^2.2"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4":{
            "App\\": "app"
        }
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php


use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'config/config.php';



$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => $config]);



$container = $app->getContainer();
$container['view'] = new \Slim\Views\PhpRenderer("resources/views/");

require 'app/routes.php';

$app->run();
```

**routes.php**

```
<?php

$app->get('/', 'App\Controllers\HomeController::index');
```

**Controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Controller {

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(\Slim\Container $container){
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function __get($propriedade){
        if($this->container->{$propriedade}){
            return $this->container->{$propriedade};
        }
    }

}
```

**HomeController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use App\Controllers\Controller;

class HomeController extends Controller{


    public function index($request, $response){
        $response = $this->view->render($response, 'template.phtml');
        return $response;
    }

}
```

*Estou usando o php 5.4*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que ao invés disto (`::`):

```
  $app->get('/', 'App\Controllers\HomeController::index');
```

Você deve fazer isto (`:`):

```
  $app->get('/', 'App\Controllers\HomeController:index');
```

Pois com o `::` o **Slim** vai tentar chamar o método como se ele fosse estático, ou seja, usando assim `HomeController:index` para o Slim seria o mesmo que:

```
<?php

$x = new HomeController;
$x->index();
```

O que seria um objeto instanciado, e assim `HomeController::index` seria o mesmo que chamar assim:

```
<?php

HomeController::index();
```

Essa ultima maneira faz o método não reconhecer o `$this`, já que não é um objeto, logo ele não estará acessível no contexto.

**Nota:** se você estivesse com o `E_STRICT` habilitado iria receber esta seguinte mensagem de erro:

> **Strict Standards:** Non-static method HomeController::index() should not be called statically in c:\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse.php on line 32
>
> **Strict Standards:** call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method HomeController::index() should not be called statically in c:\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse.php on line 41

Comment: Vlw pela ajuda, agora funcionou certo.